# Delete a json value which is inside a set of json

Tags: javascript, angular, foreach

I have a JSON as below.

```
{
"key" : "Balance",
"translation" : [ 
    {
        "language" : "English",
        "value" : "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "language" : "German",
        "value" : "faq"
    }
]
}
```

I'm passing the language "English" and the language and its value should delete. There are many keys so I'm using for loop in my function to get that language.

```
this._work.forEach( ( translation ) => {
        translation.translation.forEach( data => delete data.language[ language ] );
    } );
```

`this._work` contains the above json value. Here the language and its value not deleting. What I'm missing?

Comment: _"I have a JSON as below"_ - No, that's not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). What you have there is an object -> [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Answer (score 1):

In your solution,  `delete data.language[ language ]` will not work since `data.language['English']` is undefined. This deletion technique is generally used when you want to remove by using `key` from an object, not row in an array.

You can use `filter` instead of using `forEach`.

```
this._work.forEach( ( row ) => {
   row.translation = row.translation.filter( translation => translation.language !== translation );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

**Aside note:** There is nothing called JSON en js, what you have is a js object.

Actually you're trying to delete the attribute "English" from the string `language`, which is wrong and doesn't make sense.

For example:

```
delete data.language["English"]
```

I recommend you to use the function `Array.prototype.filter` as follow:

```js
let data = {
  "key": "Balance",
  "translation": [{
      "language": "English",
      "value": "abc"
    },
    {
      "language": "German",
      "value": "faq"
    }
  ]
},
    language = "English";
    
data.translation = data.translation.filter(({language: lang}) => lang !== language);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Is there anything specific to assign in flower bracket?

Comment: @Kirataka sorry, I didn't understand.

Comment: u have declared this `({language: lang})` in flower braces. Is it for a specific reason?

Comment: @Kirataka this is just to use a destructuring assignment of the property language, there is not a reason, it's just for a fancy approach, otherwise, in the handler of the function `filter` you have to access the property as follow: `object.language`

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   property: 'value',
   language: 'English'
}
```

`delete` instruction needs a property provided to be deleted. like `delete data.property` or `delete data.language`. In the code, you provided `data.language[language]` points to a value. If you want to delete the language property if the value is `English`, then the code you needs is

```
this._work.forEach( ( translation ) => {
        translation.translation.forEach( data => if (language === data.language) { delete data.language; });
    } );
```

as a result you would get:

```
{
"key" : "Balance",
"translation" : [ 
    {
        "value" : "abc"
    }, 
    {
        "language" : "German",
        "value" : "faq"
    }
]
}
```